# Javascript recursion problem to display children node

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I have an huge input array of nodes with children array that contains a list of id of nodes, I've got help to create a tree function that loop through the input array to create a tree.

the input :

```js
[
  {
    "neo4jId": "1",
    "nodeName": "A",
    "children": ["12", "13", "14"]
  },

  {
    "neo4jId": "12",
    "nodeName": "AA",
    "children": ["1", "21", "22", "23"]
  },
  {
    "neo4jId": "13",
    "nodeName": "AB",
    "children": ["1"]
  },
  {
    "neo4jId": "14",
    "nodeName": "AC",
    "children": ["12"]
  },
  {
    "neo4jId": "21",
    "nodeName": "AAA",
    "children": ["1"]
  },
  {
    "neo4jId": "22",
    "nodeName": "AAB",
    "children": ["13"]
  },
  {
    "neo4jId": "23",
    "nodeName": "AAC",
    "children": []
  }
]
```

The expected output is :

```js
[
  {
    "key": "1",
    "data": {
      "nodeName": "A"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "key": "12",
        "data": {
          "nodeName": "AA"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "key": "21",
            "data": {
              "nodeName": "AAA"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "key": "1",
                "data": { "nodeName": "A" },
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "key": "22",
            "data": {
              "nodeName": "AAB"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "key": "13",
                "data": { "nodeName": "AB" },
                "children": [
                  {
                    "key": "1",
                    "data": { "nodeName": "A" },
                    "children": []
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "key": "23",
            "data": {
              "nodeName": "AAC"
            },
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "key": "1",
            "data": {
              "nodeName": "A"
            },
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "key": "13",
        "data": {
          "nodeName": "AB"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "key": "1",
            "data": {
              "nodeName": "A"
            },
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "key": "14",
        "data": {
          "nodeName": "AC"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "key": "12",
            "data": { "nodeName": "AA" },
            "children": [
              {
                "key": "21",
                "data": {
                  "nodeName": "AAA"
                },
                "children": [
                  {
                    "key": "1",
                    "data": { "nodeName": "A" },
                    "children": []
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "key": "22",
                "data": {
                  "nodeName": "AAB"
                },
                "children": [
                  {
                    "key": "13",
                    "data": { "nodeName": "AB" },
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "key": "1",
                        "data": { "nodeName": "AA" },
                        "children": []
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "key": "23",
                "data": {
                  "nodeName": "AAC"
                },
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "key": "1",
                "data": {
                  "nodeName": "A"
                },
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

For the moment, and with this function :

```js
const getTree = (data = []) => {
  const getObject = (key) =>
      (({ children, noRecursion = [], ...o }) => ({
        ...o,
        children: [...children.map(getObject), ...noRecursion.map((key) => ({ ...r[key], children: [] }))],
      }))(r[key]),
    c = new Set(),
    r = Object.fromEntries(data.map(({ neo4jId: key, children = [], ...data }) => [key, { key, data, children }])),
    keys = Object.keys(r);

  keys.forEach((k) => {
    r[k].children.forEach((l) => {
      if (r[l].children.length < r[k].children.length) {
        r[l].noRecursion = [...r[l].children];
        r[l].children.length = 0;
      }
    });
  });

  keys.forEach((k) => r[k].children.forEach(Set.prototype.add, c));

  console.log(keys.filter((k) => !c.has(k)).map(getObject));

  return keys.filter((k) => !c.has(k)).map(getObject);
};
```

The expected output is not printed correctly..

I'm looking for this architecture :
[image: expected output]

For each node, I should verify if it not contains his parents id's OR if it not contains a children's root node, if not I display a tree normaly inside, else I should display the tree founded (from root node or from parents nodes) but with only one level (to avoid recursion)

***The root parent is alyways the first item of input data***

And the output should be an array with only one node

have you an idea how to achieve this with javascript ?

Comment: You have cycles in your sample input. Id 1 has Id 2 as a child, and Id 2 has Id 1 as a child. Your output looks wrong because, for example, the item with key=1 should not be at the top level, because it is the child of another node. Was your sample input and output only roughly illustrative, and not intended to be correct?

Comment: the id 1 is a root beacause the length of the property 'children' inside. the max depth is 4 level . you're right : 6 should not be root node, but a children of 5 and HE MUST HAVE 4 as children (because we want just 4 deepth level), I update my expected output :)

Comment: You have not explained why id 1 is the root. What is special about the length of the children of id 1?

Comment: the  length of the children of id 1 is 4, and for others is 1 or 0, so the id 1 is the parent_node

Comment: In my case is not possible, there is only one item that have a big children

Comment: In my example I have juste 1->2->1 and I stop because 1 is a parent node, so each time I have 1 I make it as a leaf

Comment: Yes I want to say root node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const data = [{"neo4jId":"1","nodeName":"A","children":["12","13","14"]},{"neo4jId":"12","nodeName":"AA","children":["1","21","22","23"]},{"neo4jId":"13","nodeName":"AB","children":["1"]},{"neo4jId":"14","nodeName":"AC","children":["12"]},{"neo4jId":"21","nodeName":"AAA","children":["1"]},{"neo4jId":"22","nodeName":"AAB","children":["13"]},{"neo4jId":"23","nodeName":"AAC","children":[]}]

const [root] = data

const f = ({neo4jId:key, nodeName, children:c}, s={}) => ({
  key,
  data:{nodeName},
  children:s[key]?[]:(s[key]=1, c.map(key =>
    data.find(({neo4jId:i}) => i===key)).map(i=>f(i,{...s})))
})

console.log(f(root))
```

Comment: I get an emty array when I try to use your solution with my input data.. :(

Comment: @Tania12 I updated the answer. I think this general approach should work. It prevents all cycles by setting children to an empty array if it occurs more than once in a cycle

Comment: What If I want to use the first item as a root node ?

Comment: @Tania12 then just do `const root = data[0]`

Comment: It almost! for the first node it's exactly what I expect, the second must be (If you saw my update question) : AB ->A and the last one : AC->AA->(AAA,AAB,AAC,A) with ONLY their first level (because AA is a child of root node)

Comment: each time I found a node that is child of parent node OR a parent (or parent ++) of this node, I want to dispay the children nodes but without looping inside them (to avoid recursion)

Comment: @Tania12  Please explain with ids instead of letters like AA, since that makes it easier for me to understand. Right now, I don't understand what the rule needs to be. What my code currently does is: any time I see any node appear anywhere beneath itself in the tree (directly or indirectly), I just set children to be empty.

Comment: 14 -> 12 ->(21,22,23,1) and the ids in () should display their FISTS LEVEL children only, this is exactly what I'm lookin for..

Comment: I don't know why you want it to be `12 ->(21,22,23,1)`, when your data says the child ids are `(1,21,22,23)`. Is the rule that if anything appears more than once, it should be last in the list of children? I also don't understand what you mean by first level children only. I'm only ever including direct children within any particular node.

Comment: The order does'nt matter, (21,22,23,1) or (1,21,22,23) is the same thing.. for the other question : for example I'm in node 22 and I found 13 as children, since 13 is a children of root node, I want to show 13 -> 1 insiden just 13 ->1 without loop into 1 children beacause it will trigger an infinite loop

Comment: I don't understand your English. It currently goes 1 -> 12 -> 22 -> 13 -> 1, and the second occurrence of 1 has no children, which prevents the infinite loop. Are you saying that's wrong? How should it be?

Comment: Yes that's it, but for the third node it's wrong because it should return : 1->14->12->(tree of children of 12'id), sorry for my english I do my best ^^

Comment: @Tania12 aha, I think I understand now. Yes, there was a bug in my code. Does my latest version work?

Comment: What was the error in the previous code please ?

Comment: @Tania12  a fresh copy of `s` needed to be passed each time by doing `{...s}`. When it was the same `s` in the old code, if something appeared in one branch, it would be incorrectly treated as having already appeared in other branches.

Answer (score 1):

An approach.

```js
const
    getTree = data => {
        const
            getNodes = (keys, seen = []) => keys.map(key => ({
                ...nodes[key],
                children: seen.includes(key)
                    ? []
                    : getNodes(nodes[key].children, [...seen, key])
            })),
            nodes = Object.fromEntries(data.map(({ neo4jId: key, children, ...data }) => [key, { key, data, children }]));
            
        return getNodes([data[0].neo4jId]);
    },
    data = [
        { neo4jId: "1",  nodeName: "A",   children: ["12", "13", "14"] },
        { neo4jId: "12", nodeName: "AA",  children: ["1", "21", "22", "23"] },
        { neo4jId: "13", nodeName: "AB",  children: ["1"] },
        { neo4jId: "14", nodeName: "AC",  children: ["12"] },
        { neo4jId: "21", nodeName: "AAA", children: ["1"] },
        { neo4jId: "22", nodeName: "AAB", children: ["13"] },
        { neo4jId: "23", nodeName: "AAC", children: [] }
    ],
    tree = getTree(data);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is the solution!! thank you I spent 4days looking for this approach

Comment: For nodeName variable I want to put it into a data object like this : {data : {nodeName : 'XXX}}

Comment: When I change the input data I get a wrong result.. :(

Comment: the goal is to display a tree that respects the following rule:
during the construction of a node, check if the children is not a parent or a great grandparent or a child of the parent, if this is not the case I display the node and its children, otherwise I shows only children and I stop, please take a look at my updated question

Comment: I had misunderstood the exercise before, what I would like to do is create the tree by displaying its children without depth limits, I just have to stop when I see a node of the root or a node of its children, to avoid infinite loops,else I continue to create children nodes

Comment: I'm so sorry about that...

Comment: the first item in input data is always the root node, @Andrew Parks founds a solution and seems working, please take a look, and any other alternative will be appreciate (I'm still learning ^^)

Comment: It works too!! big thanks to you, sorry if i bothered you a lot :))))))

Answer (score 0):

This ain't a tree, this is a directed graph and looks like this. *(Arrows pointing from "parent" to "child")*

[image: tree]

And a snippet how to resolve it:

```js
let data = [
  {
    "neo4jId": "1",
    "nodeName": "node_parent",
    "children": ["2", "3", "4", "5"]
  },

  {
    "neo4jId": "2",
    "nodeName": "children 2",
    "children": ["1"]
  },
  {
    "neo4jId": "3",
    "nodeName": "children 3",
    "children": ["1", "2"]
  },
  {
    "neo4jId": "4",
    "nodeName": "children 4",
    "children": ["5"]
  },
  {
    "neo4jId": "5",
    "nodeName": "children 5",
    "children": ["6"]
  },
  {
    "neo4jId": "6",
    "nodeName": "children 6",
    "children": ["4"]
  }
]

const byId = {};

for(let item of data) 
  byId[item.neo4jId] = item;

for(let item of data) 
  item.children = item.children.map(id => byId[id]);
  
// check your browsers console
// don't attempt to log this in the snippet, 
// it will crash the snippet.

console.log(byId[1]);  // let's start somewhere
```

Comment: Please take a look at the expected output, I have max depth of four levels and with your code it loop recursivly..

Comment: @Tania12 If the max depth is four levels the expected output is wrong. `node_parent » children 2 » node_parent` is 3 levels and should be `node_parent » children 2 » node_parent » children 2` (4 levels). This is an example, but also applies for `children 3`, `children 4`, etc.

Comment: The rule here is when I found node_parent id I stop going in deep, please take a look at :  node_parent » children 5 » children 6 » children 5 and compare it with node_parent » children 2 » node_parent :)

Comment: it's `node_parent » children 5 » children 6 » children 4 » children 5` but children 5 is not the parent of children 4 so is this even an abort condition?